# Display output from python in aspx page

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, visual-studio, ironpython

Question from a .net newbie

Hello,

I am trying to display output from my python code in aspx page.

Below is .net c# code that executes by the click of Button1.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptEngine eng = Python.CreateEngine();
    dynamic scope = eng.CreateScope();
    eng.ExecuteFile(@"C:\path\hello.py", scope);
    Label1.Text = //display output in Label1
}
```

Below is the sample python script.

```
print "hello"
```

Could you please tell me how to display "hello" in Label1.Text?

Also any kind of information regarding passing data between python and asp.net is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: what does your `eng.ExecuteFile()` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all your result in variable a

Example:

Python

```
a = ""
a += "hello world\n"
a += "==========="
```

In C#

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\path\hello.py", scope);
var result = scope.GetVariable("a");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: ScriptEngine is not supporting. what should i download any dll?

Comment: Moreover, if I have 1k lines of Python code then then I have to put only the output in the variable NOT the 1k lines of code in variable....right?? please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @SunnySandeep Just install the nuget package IronPython 2.2.7 and add the directives:
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;